# Ant build file issue

Tags: java, ant, build

Hi I have a problem with ant build.xml and it works but sometimes not the first time or works on some computers and others not

so here it is:

```
<project name="My-java-api" default="dist-api" basedir=".">

<description>
    Java API Buildfile
</description>

<property name="src" location="src"/>
<property name="build" location="build"/>
<property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
<property name="libs"  location="libs"/>

<!--if we don't remove folders, when we call compile-api
and classes have already been built, it doesn't build again-->

<target name="-init-api" depends="clean"
        description="Create folders libs and build">
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${libs}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
</target>

 <!-- Here I call another buildfile of submodule located at the tree indicated I am 
 sure the other buildfile works perfect -->

<target name="-pre-build-api" depends="-init-api"
        description="Create jelly jar and copy it to libs folder">
    <ant dir="../Libraries/jelly/core/"
         antfile="build.xml"
         target="standalone-jar"/>
    <copy todir="${libs}">
        <fileset
                dir="../Libraries/jelly/core/dist"
                includes="jelly-standalone*.jar" />
    </copy>
</target>

 <!--so now I create this classpath to use for making jar-->

<path id="lib.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${libs}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

 <!--I compile source code including the jar that I have just copied to libs-->
<target name="compile-api" depends="-pre-build-api" >
    <javac srcdir="${src}"
           includeantruntime="false"
           destdir="${build}"
           classpathref="lib.classpath">
    </javac>
</target>
<!-- here i make jar with the classes and using the jar from external project,
I want just one jar for everything  -->

<target name="dist-api" depends="compile-api" >

    <jar jarfile="${dist}/name-java-api-0.1.jar" basedir="${build}" >
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${libs}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
    <delete dir="${libs}"/>
</target>
```

EDIT: failonerror="false" added to all the delete lines

I am not used to ant and I have been trying and trying and it just doesn't quite work. I wish I could just use command line but can't.
Strangely most of the time if run it 2 times it works but the first time really weird staff happen: either doesn't compile, either classes are duplicated. What could be the reason? thanks a lot

Comment: What task does it fail on?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the failures? What task do you run? What happens?

Comment: I'm also not clear on what you mean by "classes are duplicated".

Comment: one of the classes is duplicated MzSystemModel.class and MzSystemModel$1.class then there is MzSystemModel$State.class but this one is for the enum right?

Comment: `MzSystemModel$1` isn't a duplicate, it's an anonymous inner class (such as a `new Runnable() { public void run() { ... } }`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you explain why it might fail? A quick look, and I see that your *compile-api* task is dependent upon your *lib.classpath* task, but it isn't included in *compile-api*'s dependences. That can cause a build script to work sometimes and not others.

Also, *lib.classpath* is dependent upon the *lib* directory being created, so it should also be dependent upon *-init-api*.

And, you should ***never ever*** have anything depend upon *clean*. Ant builds are setup, so they don't have to execute unnecessary steps. For example, if you change just one source file, only that source file gets recompiled. You break the whole idea of a build script forcing a clean each time a build is done.

---

Looking a bit closer at your build.xml, I realize there are some other issues.

Here's a `build.xml` with corrected dependencies.

```
<project name="My-java-api" default="dist-api" basedir=".">

    <description>
        Java API Buildfile
    </description>

    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>
    <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
    <property name="libs"  location="libs"/>

    <!--if we don't remove folders, when we call compile-api -->
    <!-- and classes have already been built, it doesn't build again-->

    <target name="-init-api"
        description="Create folders libs and build">
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${libs}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Here I call another buildfile of submodule located at the tree indicated I am -->
    <!--sure the other buildfile works perfect -->

    <target name="-pre-build-api" depends="-init-api"
        description="Create jelly jar and copy it to libs folder">
        <ant dir="../Libraries/jelly/core/"
            antfile="build.xml"
            target="standalone-jar"/>
        <copy todir="${libs}">
            <fileset
                dir="../Libraries/jelly/core/dist"
                includes="jelly-standalone*.jar" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!--so now I create this classpath to use for making jar-->

    <target name="lib.classpath"
        depends="-pre-build-api">
        <path id="lib.classpath"
            depends="-pre-build-api">
            <fileset dir="${libs}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </path>
    </target>

    <!--I compile source code including the jar that I have just copied to libs-->
    <target name="compile-api"
        depends="lib.classpath" >
        <javac srcdir="${src}"
            includeantruntime="false"
            destdir="${build}"
            classpathref="lib.classpath">
        </javac>
    </target>
    <!-- here i make jar with the classes and using the jar from external project,
    I want just one jar for everything  -->

    <target name="dist-api"
        depends="compile-api" >

        <jar jarfile="${dist}/name-java-api-0.1.jar" basedir="${build}" >
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${libs}" includes="**/*.jar" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
        <delete dir="${build}"/>
        <delete dir="${dist}"/>
        <delete dir="${libs}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**NOTE**: `dist-api` *depends upon* `compile-api` which *depends upon* `lib.classpath` which *depends upon* `pre-build-api` which _depends upon `-init.api`. There is nothing dependent upon `clean`.

Comment: thanks for your help David W the only problem is I get error: build.xml:33: path doesn't support the "depends" attribute

Comment: if I remove the "depends" attribute then one of the classes in jar file is duplicated and then I dont get error on build but when I sue this file in another project it fails

Comment: @vallllll - Whoops, that's not a target! This `<classpath>` will be executed before all targets, and if the `lib` directory isn't there with the required jars, this will fail. We need to put this either into the `compile-api` target, or make it a target that `compile-api` depends upon.

Comment: @vallllll I updated my build.xml. The `lib.classpath` is in its own target. The problem is that you are setting your classpath outside of all targets which means setting the classpath is called first. If there is no `lib` directory the build will fail either because lib.classpath is empty or because the `lib` directory doesn't exist and the classpath fails to get created. You have to execute this ***after*** `-pre-build-api` target is called. Alternatives is to place this at the end of `-pre-build-api target or in the beginning of `compile-api` target.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to complain if the directories are not there, as would be the case the first time you run it. You might want to add a failonerror="false" attribute to the delete tasks.

For future reference, ant is not really used that much anymore for building Java - most people have gone over to maven.

Comment: thanks I added that I added this to all my delete scripts but still did not fix the whole problem.

Comment: Not everyone has gone to Maven. We use Ant.

Comment: I support both ANT and Maven builds. Would you believe 80% of Java builds (certainly in Enterprises) still use ANT? Part of this is inertia, part of this is legacy and finally there's plain old fear of something new :-)